# Combine - LEAD and LAG with NULL records inbetween - Group/rank?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table which stores Tasks of every person with ContactID, StartDutyDateTime, EndDutyDateTime. With a LEAD/LEG function - I can find out - the "begin" of the Duty - and the "End" of the Duty.
With caclulating REST Time inbetween different Task - I can determin if this a new day or just a short break.
I can not selct the DATE of the first - and check the last Time - as Duties are going also over midnight.

[image: FullRecord]

With Lead/Leg I find:

[image: if row is also Start/End of Duty - the time will show - otherwise it is NULL]

how can I merge them into ONE row per duty together - I tried Rank/Row numbers... but this gives me nonsense results.

I would need

- 13.05.2014 05:00:00 - 13.05.2014 13:25:00
- 17.05.2014 05:35:00 - 17.05.2014 13:20:00

How can I get the "minimum/maximum" DateTime per Workingday (considering it is also going over midnight)?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: MS SQL 2014 database

Comment: I filtered now all records - where both columns are not null. 
In a CTE I used Lead - in case of DutyEndDateTime=0
I got now a list with is showing items expected from above - but very slow over a few thousand records. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've misunderstood what you're after, but it sounds like a simple group by StartDutyDate then min & max.

Hope this helps.

Rhys

```
select
    cast(StartDutyDateTime as date) as WorkingDay,
    min(StartDutyDateTime) as [Min],
    max(EndDutyDateTime) as [Max]
from
    dbo.MyTable
group by 
    cast(StartDutyDateTime as date)
```

Comment: Well, WorkingDay will not work - just imagine one Duty from 22:00 until 23:45 - next from 00:20 until 03:15.
The Complete Duty Period would be 22:00 until 03:15
If I would use WorkingDay... this would result in 2 records - not in one.

Comment: @BjoernRoethig - could you update your question with some sample data that reflects what you describe? There needs to be something that indicates the 2 duties you mention are part of the same duty period? It would help if the data was text (rather than a picture).